# this is showing wrong output when i am giving this more then one test cases

Tags: c++

this is codechef January challenge's first problem[codechef](https://www.codechef.com/JAN21C/problems/DIVTHREE).
When i am  giving more than one test case ,it is giving wrong output. and when i  am giving one test cases it is going right.

```
my code:-
        

  #include<iostream>
       using namespace std;
         int long long N;
          int main()
       {
        int i,j, N,t,d,k,sum=0;
         cin>>t;
       for(j=1;j<=t;j++)
{
        cin>>N>>k>>d;
          for(i=0;i<N;i++)
            {
              int num;
                cin >> num;
                 sum += num;
            }

                  for(i=0;i<N;i++) 
              {
                 sum= int(sum/k);
                 if(sum>d)
                  {
                     cout<<d<<endl;
                     
                   }
                   
                   else
                   {
                       cout<<sum<<endl;
                    }
              }
          }
        return 0;
       }
```

Comment: Please add the problem description as text, instead of linking to an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is in the wrong place, it should be inside the test case loop not after  it. You also need to print a newline after every result

Your code is like this

```
   for(j=1;j<=t;j++)
   {
       ...
   }
   if(sum>d)
   {
        cout<<d;
   }
   else 
        cout<<sum;
```

but it should be like this

```
   for(j=1;j<=t;j++)
   {
       ...
       if(sum>d)
            cout<<d<<'\n';
       else 
            cout<<sum<<'\n';
   }
```

Mistakes like this are **much** easier to spot if you get into the habit of indenting your code consistently.

Another error is that you don't reset `sum` to zero for each test case. Your loop should also look like this

```
   for(j=1;j<=t;j++)
   {
       sum=0;
       ...
   }
```

Some sloppy mistakes. To be a programmer you really have to pay attention to the details.

For free, here's another tip. You don't need to use an array for this problem. To add up numbers you don't need to put them all in an array first and then add them up later. You can just add them up as you input them.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    sum += num;
}
```

Comment: still showing same error

Comment: @AnjaliKaur So what is that error? Give us a clue.

Comment: So could you give an example of the input and the wrong output. Could you show your latest code. Obviously you are still making some mistake, but without this information I can't say what it is. If you want me to help you have to give as much information as possible. All you are telling at the moment is that it is not working, which doesn't help very much.

Comment: Another bug seems to be that you are using the value of `N` before it gets a value `int arr[N]; ... cin>>N>>k>>d;` but as I explained you shouldn't be using an array at all.

Comment: when N is one.....it is showing output as per the test case.

Comment: but for more than one N(num) value....it is showing right output+number.  like if it should be 7 for 1(t),2(N),for 7(d).,20,36 but it is showing 7,2........or respectively next test case 1,3,3,300,1,1,1. it should be 1 but it is showing 1,0,0

Comment: i updated the ques, you can check

Comment: @AnjaliKaur Well the code you have posted in not the same as the code in my answer. All the right code is there but it's in the wrong places.

Comment: @AnjaliKaur Your code `int sum=0; ... for(j=1;j<=t;j++) { ...` my code `for(j=1;j<=t;j++) { int sum = 0;` Obviously the sum must be set to zero for every test case. Not just for the first one.
{

Comment: also you can check ques, which i have hyperlinked

Comment: Your code `for(j=1;j<=t;j++) { ... for(i=0;i<N;i++) { ... cout<<d<<endl; } }` My code `for(j=1;j<=t;j++) { ... for(i=0;i<N;i++) { ... } cout<<d<<endl; }`. Again you must print out once at the end of each test case, not in the middle of a test case.

Comment: @AnjaliKaur If you learned to indent your code consistently it would be much easier to spot these errors.

Comment: but why this code is showing output+number....only for more than one num.

Comment: @AnjaliKaur Because of the errors I've described. Your loops are wrong, but this only shows itself when you go around the loop more than once.

Comment: For instance, it doesn't matter that you don't set the sum to zero at the beginning of each test case when there is only one test case. But when there is more than one test case it does.

Comment: And it doesn't matter that you are printing the result after every number (instead of at the end of the test case) when there is only one number. But when there is more than one number this error matters.